# Encode a video by eliminating repeating frames - Matlab

Tags: matlab, video, video-encoding

I want to find a method to eliminate the repeating frames from a video. If I consider a video which will repeatedly show the same frame for 5 seconds, I want to include only one frame of that in the video and make it visible for 5 seconds. In here I am looking forward to minimize the file size by eliminating duplicate frames. Is there a method to do this using Matlab?

Comment: Look at cross correlation or sum-square intensity differences as a means to compare them maybe.

Comment: A tricky part will be when you will play the file. You cannot use any random player which play at a constant fps rate. You will need to attach a `for how long to display this frame` metadata to each frame and a player which can handle that.

Comment: Are you creating the video in Matlab or does it already exist? Is this a matter of simply detecting which frames are repeated or not encoding these frames to begin with? Please edit your question to clarify.

Comment: @horchler Yes I am trying to create a video using Matlab. I want the help in creating the video which provide a way to mention the duration of each frame and a way to play it again.

Comment: @Hoki Can you direct me with a solid method to change the metadata data of a video frame?

Comment: Sorry, video processing is far from my domain of expertise. When I create video or animations with Matlab, they are indeed quite big, then I typically use [handbrake](https://handbrake.fr/) to convert (and compress) them. Depending on how much movement there is in the video, the final file size is between 10% and 30% of the original file size, without significant loss of quality. This is well enough for my needs. If you need to investigate more encoders/decoders, the answer by @horchler is full of interesting links (more than i could direct you to).

Comment: @Asanga Ranasinghe: "changing the metadata" will depend highly on what codec (and even what implementation) you're using. I think it's generally a bad idea (better to just create the video correctly in the first place) and this isn't really the right forum. There aren't many direct tools for this I'm aware of other than the two extremes of re-encoding the video or looking at the raw hexadecimal of the video's header/footer. Incorrectly editing  the metadata can also corrupt all or part of your video file. If a format doesn't support variable frame rates, editing the file won't give you that.

Comment: For codec specifics, [start here](http://wiki.multimedia.cx/?title=Category:Video_Codecs). Try the [Doom9](http://forum.doom9.org/forumdisplay.php?f=17) forums for questions about codecs and hacking the metadata.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your movie is just a series of stills that you wish to show as a slideshow/presentation with a fixed five second delay, then you should be able to used the [`'FrameRate'`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/videowriter-class.html#propname_FrameRate) property for the [`VideoWriter`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/videowriter-class.html) class. Try something like this example:

```
writerObj = VideoWriter('peaks.mp4','MPEG-4');
writerObj.FrameRate = 0.2; % One frame every 5 seconds
open(writerObj);

Z = peaks;
surf(Z);
for k = 1:4:20 
   surf(sin(2*pi*k/20)*Z,Z);
   writeVideo(writerObj,getframe);
end
close(writerObj);
```

However, the frame-rate property cannot be varied over the course of your movie, so the more general form of your question is fundamentally an issue of encoder support for [variable frame-rate encoding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable_frame_rate). Most modern encoders (e.g., H.264 implementations) are not designed to explicitly handle this, but rather have heuristics that can detect when content is not changing and efficiently encode the data (particularly if multi-pass encoding is used). Unfortunately, Matlab (I'm assuming that you've been using the `VideoWriter` class) doesn't really provide great deal of fidelity in this respect. I'm not even sure what inter-frame encoding settings are used for MPEG-4 with H.264 videos.

If the [MPEG-4 with H.264 videos](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/videowriter-class.html#inputarg_profile) produced by `VideoWriter` are unacceptable, I'd recommend exporting your video in the highest quality possible (or lossless) and then learn to use a full-fledged encoding framework/library ([ffmpeg](http://ffmpeg.org), [libav](https://libav.org), [x264](http://www.videolan.org/developers/x264.html)) or application to encode to the quality and size you desire. Apparently [Handbrake](https://handbrake.fr) has support for [variable frame-rate encoding](https://trac.handbrake.fr/wiki/VariableFrameRate), though it's not necessarily designed for what you may want I've not tested it. Or export your individual still frames and use actually video editing software (e.g. iMovie on OS X). There are also likely dedicated applications that can create a movie from a slideshow/presentation (both PowerPoint and Keynote can do this).

Within Matlab, another alternative, is to use a codec that explicitly supports variable frame rates – QuickTime's [image-based codecs](http://support.apple.com/kb/sp521): Photo JPEG (not to be confused with Motion-JPEG), Photo PNG (a.k.a. Apple PNG), and Photo TIFF (a.k.a. Apple Tiff). You can encode content directly using these codecs with my [`QTWriter`](http://horchler.github.io/QTWriter/), which is [available on Github](https://github.com/horchler/QTWriter). Note however, that on OS X 10.9+, QuickTime Player converts lossless variable frame-rate Photo PNG and Photo TIFF movies to lossy fixed frame-rate H.264 (Photo JPEG movies are not converted). See [my note towards the bottom of this page](https://github.com/horchler/QTWriter) for further details and a workaround.